# Capture camera and show preview in div

Tags: javascript, camera, windows-phone, windows-store

I am in the process of developing a windows store app which shows a preview of the camera and then (obviously) allows the user to take pictures.

In my following code, the entire screen shows a display of the camerapreview, and on-click takes a picture. I want the preview to be shown in a div and use a seperate button to actually take the picture. I have read various tutorials but they all use the full screen to take pictures. Is there any way to solve my problem?

I am using Visual Studio to develop a Windows Store app in Javascript.

```
function takepicture() {
        var captureUI = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).then(function (capturedItem) {
            if (capturedItem) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "User captured a photo."
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "User didn't capture a photo."
            }
        });
    }
```

The function gets called onload. I have read up on the API-info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.aspx), but could not find out how. Am I missing something?

My general idea is to use the following setup:

```
<body onload="showPreview();">
    <div id="cameraPreview">

    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="capture" onclick="takePicture();">Take Picture</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i have some problems doing this when i tried it.
But i finally succeded. Here's how to do

## Html

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100px">
    <video id="cameraPreview"></video>
</div>
```

The camera preview will be displayed in the video element.
Remember to set the size of the parent div, or you will see anything

## Initialize media elements

```
// div is the dom element that will contain the camera preview
// div should be a video element
var mediaRec = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
var div = document.getElementById("cameraPreview");
var settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
```

## Get the camera device

```
var deviceList = [];
function enumerateCameras() {
    var deviceInfo = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;
    deviceInfo.findAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.videoCapture).then(function (devices) {
        // Add the devices to deviceList                                                                                                               
        if (devices.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
                deviceList.push(devices[i]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No devices found");
        }
    }, function () { console.log("error");});
}
```

Call this after initializations.
Also, deviceList here is a global array.

Once you get the devices list, get the 1st one and add it to the settings

```
settings.videoDeviceId = deviceList[0];
```

Then initialize the mediaRec element using initializeAsync, and bind it the the div.

```
mediaRec.initializeAsync().then(function () {
    div.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaRec); // Set the div data source. Most important part
    div.play(); // read the source and display it
})
```

I hope it helps you (and i hope it still works. I can't even try it, i'm not on window atm)

To take the picture, yours might work. I don't have the same code, but if yours take picture, then why not. Ask me if you want to see what i done to take pictures.

Comment: I am not able to get the preview. When running the app, loading appears to happen for quite a while. Then loading stops and nothing happens.

Comment: Hope that will work! Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I forgot to give you the right html code.
It should contain a video element. (See in my answer)

Comment: I actually tried that, it didn't work. Perhaps it is my interpretation of the js. Do I put it in an init function?

Comment: You should see how to use winJS ui elements.
Personally, i have a winjs ui element that defines my html page.
Once it's loaded, i create a new camera object on wich i call a showCameraPreview() function.


But to make it more simple, just make a button that will call your showPreview() function, just to be sure the page is loaded correctly.
Doing this, what does it do ? Any ouput ? Any error ?

Comment: Wifi is down here and I have no time to investigate why it does not work for me. I will read up on winJS ui elements later. Will accept your answer for now and get back to trying to fix this later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.
I can give you a full working code if you want (It will take me about 10mn to re-write it correctly, since there's a lot of debug code in my file). Just ask me. But there might be a problem with your code, since i'm pretty sure i've made mine work (after several hours of debug)

Comment: I would be really pleased with your source. But not now, I want to try it out when I get home, before giving up the fight ;)

Comment: Ok, I still can't get it to work. Could you please show me your source?

Comment: I ran a breakpoint, the actual playing never gets called. As if the initialiseAsync never runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54998/discussion-between-larta-and-matthijs).

Comment: @Larta Would you have a working Jsfiddle? I tried your code in a browser but it doesn't get access to the camera.